# Implicit object casting during function calls

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

With reference to the code provided below, in the main() method the actual parameter passed to the static sort() function has type String[]( variable a) but the formal parameter of the sort() function has type Comparable[]. How is this possible since the two types seem mismatched to me? Is there some sort of implicit object casting that applies during function calls that i don't know about? Any help would be appreciated.

Merge.java

Below is the syntax highlighted version of Merge.java from §2.2 Mergesort.

```
/******************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac Merge.java
 *  Execution:    java Merge < input.txt
 *  Dependencies: StdOut.java StdIn.java
 *   
 *   
 *  Sorts a sequence of strings from standard input using mergesort.
 *   
 *  % more tiny.txt
 *  S O R T E X A M P L E
 *
 *  % java Merge < tiny.txt
 *  A E E L M O P R S T X                 [ one string per line ]
 *    
 *  % more words3.txt
 *  bed bug dad yes zoo ... all bad yet
 *  
 *  % java Merge < words3.txt
 *  all bad bed bug dad ... yes yet zoo    [ one string per line ]
 *  
 ******************************************************************************/

/**
 *  The {@code Merge} class provides static methods for sorting an
 *  array using mergesort.
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation, see <a href="http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort">Section 2.2</a> of
 *  <i>Algorithms, 4th Edition</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 *  For an optimized version, see {@link MergeX}.
 *
 *  @author Robert Sedgewick
 *  @author Kevin Wayne
 */
public class Merge {

    // This class should not be instantiated.
    private Merge() { }

    // stably merge a[lo .. mid] with a[mid+1 ..hi] using aux[lo .. hi]
    private static void merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        // precondition: a[lo .. mid] and a[mid+1 .. hi] are sorted subarrays
        assert isSorted(a, lo, mid);
        assert isSorted(a, mid+1, hi);

        // copy to aux[]
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            aux[k] = a[k]; 
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid+1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if      (i > mid)              a[k] = aux[j++];
            else if (j > hi)               a[k] = aux[i++];
            else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++];
            else                           a[k] = aux[i++];
        }

        // postcondition: a[lo .. hi] is sorted
        assert isSorted(a, lo, hi);
    }

    // mergesort a[lo..hi] using auxiliary array aux[lo..hi]
    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    /**
     * Rearranges the array in ascending order, using the natural order.
     * @param a the array to be sorted
     */
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[a.length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);
        assert isSorted(a);
    }


   /***************************************************************************
    *  Helper sorting function.
    ***************************************************************************/

    // is v < w ?
    private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
    }

   /***************************************************************************
    *  Check if array is sorted - useful for debugging.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a) {
        return isSorted(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        for (int i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++)
            if (less(a[i], a[i-1])) return false;
        return true;
    }


   /***************************************************************************
    *  Index mergesort.
    ***************************************************************************/
    // stably merge a[lo .. mid] with a[mid+1 .. hi] using aux[lo .. hi]
    private static void merge(Comparable[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {

        // copy to aux[]
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            aux[k] = index[k]; 
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid+1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if      (i > mid)                    index[k] = aux[j++];
            else if (j > hi)                     index[k] = aux[i++];
            else if (less(a[aux[j]], a[aux[i]])) index[k] = aux[j++];
            else                                 index[k] = aux[i++];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a permutation that gives the elements in the array in ascending order.
     * @param a the array
     * @return a permutation {@code p[]} such that {@code a[p[0]]}, {@code a[p[1]]},
     *    ..., {@code a[p[N-1]]} are in ascending order
     */
    public static int[] indexSort(Comparable[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        int[] index = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            index[i] = i;

        int[] aux = new int[n];
        sort(a, index, aux, 0, n-1);
        return index;
    }

     {
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, index, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(a, index, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        merge(a, index, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    // print array to standard output
    private static void show(Comparable[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            StdOut.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads in a sequence of strings from standard input; mergesorts them; 
     * and prints them to standard output in ascending order. 
     *
     * @param args the command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
        Merge.sort(a);
        show(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to cast, `String` implements `Comparable`, so it is already of the required type .

Comment: For future reference, code examples should be minimal, i.e. only contain code relevant to your question. So if you have a question about two lines of code, show these two lines, not the entire program they come from. If you hadn't so neatly summarized your question before the code, I'd not have bothered trying to understand the question.

Comment: Also, on stackoverflow, you can format code by selecting it in the editor, and pressing the appropriate tool bar button. I've done so for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some sort of implicit object casting that applies

Casting isn't something you do on objects, it's something you do on *values* (such as an object *reference*). The *object* is unaffected by casting. But there's no casting here.

Leaving aside primitive types, a variable or paramter of type `X` can be assigned a value of type `Y` if type `Y`:

- Is the same type as `X`, or
- Is a `class` type implementing `X`, or
- Is a *subclass* or *subinterface* of `X`, directly or indirectly.

Similarly, the array type `X[]` can be assigned a value of type `Y[]` if `X` could be assigned `Y` according to the rules above.

`String` implements `Comparable`, and so you can assign a `String` to a variable or parameter of type `Comparable`. And since the array types are assignable based on their element type, `String[]` can be assigned to a variable or parameter of type `Comparable[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to function calls:

```
Comparable comparable = "hello";

String[] strings = {"hello", "world"};
Comparable[] comparables = strings;
```

Java arrays are covariant, which means that arrays are assignable if their element types are. And `String` is assignable to `Comparable` because class `String` implements the `Comparable` interface.